# Spec for method

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I have this method in my class

```
def open
  File.open(@filepath,"w") do |f|
    @gz = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(f)
    @gz.write(%[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n])
    @gz.write(%[<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">\n])
    yield self
    @gz.write(%[</urlset>])
    @gz.close
  end
end
```

How can I write a good complete spec for this method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you should consider the name of the method. If I were to call  a method called `open`, I'd not expect that it closes the file itself, but rather that I'd be responsible for calling close.

Comment: I know the method name is not consistent I will change it but for now I want help in spec

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fakefs](https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs) to interact with file system

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary filename, use that as `@filepath`, write some data, read the data back via `File.read(filename)`, unzip it, compare.